# Error runing windows application, sgfplib.dll is not found

Tags: c#, .net, dll, fingerprint

I created a windows application and that is using a secugen fingerprint scanner. I added the SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.Windows.dll and several dlls mentioned in the SDK documentation as reference in my project. Application works fine in development machine

However, when I install and run the application in other machine it's throwing this error
**Error! can not find sgfplib.dll**

I am sure that sgfplib.dll is in the bin directory and
I tried adding this dll to System32 and syswow folders but it didn't work.

- OS Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2019
- Application compiled for Win32

Any help is truly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: "8I am sure that sgfplib.dll is in the bin directory*" - how sure ?

Comment: How did you install this? Or did you just copy the bin directory over?

Comment: @00110001 I am sure, because I can see the sgfplib.dll file directly in that folder

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I created an installer project in the visual studio for my application

Answer (score -1):

Please Copy sgfplib.dll and related dlls from i386 folder to Windows\System32 and Windows\SysWow64 folder

Comment: Can you also explain "why" this will fix the problem?